# Backbone.js multiple callback apis

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection (of books) which allows the user to drill down into a single book, edit it and add/remove it to favorites.

While the basic CRUD for the books are straightforward with Backbone.js I'm not quite clear on how to can make a separate api call for the add/remove the book from the user favorites.

The best I can think of is hacking the sync method, checking the options for a specific variable and then firing a different api call. This works - but I'm entirely not sure if it's the correct way of doing things.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure in which of the below cases you fit in but hope they guide you

1) Instead of modifying the `sync` method from backbone you can write something like

```
url: function() {
  if (updateFavorite)
    return '/books/favorite';
  else
    return '/books';
}
```

2) In most other cases, when you are making CRUD actions on a single model, the url that is generate is something like `collection.url + model.id`, you can read more in [Backbone Docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url).

Answer (score 1):

You may use two collections: One with all the books, one with only the favorites.
It can be the same collection class, but for the favorites you change the "url"-property from "/books" or whatever to "/books/favorite" or whatever you like.

```
var books = new BookCollection({url: "/books"})
var favorites = new BookCollection({url: "/books/favorite"});
```

I think there may be a lot of other solutions, but that would be my approach.

Answer (score 0):

My thought is that Every BookModel must have a FavoriteBookModel nested to it.

Sharing a code that creates the nested model, also associated the models using bookId as Foreign Key in the nested Model.

```
 var BookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : '/books',
    initialize : function(){
        this.favoriteModel = new FavoriteBookModel();
        this.on('change', this.changeHandler);
        this.changeHandler();
    },
    changeHandler : function(){
        this.favoriteModel.set({ bookId : this.get('id')});
    }
  });

  var FavoriteBookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : function(){
        return '/books/'+this.get('bookId')+'/favorite';
    },
  });
```